# Set local state according to Mobx state

Tags: reactjs, mobx, setstate, mobx-react

in the component, I want to open a modal according to Mobx state. but I got confused doing that.

in Mobx I have a computed function that returns the report.

```
@observable report= null;
@computed get getErrorReport(){return this.report}
```

and in the component, if there is an error I want to open a modal which for that I need to setState the modal flag.

```
render() { 
    const { getErrorReport } = this.props.myStore!;
    if(getErrorReport) {this.setState({modalOpen:true})}
    .....
}
```

of course, this update is errorful. generally in these cases that we need `setState` in render what should be the approach?

Answer (score 3):

you may want to structure your code in such a way.

```
class MyStore {
    @observable report = null;
    // You do not need a @computed here just to return a property - access it 
    // directly
}


@inject('myStore')  // myStore is an instance of MyStore that you passed to Provider
@observer // observer will trigger a rerender if any observable prop change (report 
          // in your case)
class MyReactComponent extends React.Component {

// so you do not need a set state here 

    render() {
         // Your modal component may differ, this is example
        return (<Modal isOpened={this.props.myStore.report} />)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this case I must empty  the report to close modal. Some other components need those info. I want the component manage its Modal individually

Comment: Your requirement is controversial. If some other components need `report`, and you are unable to empty it - then it's better to bind on some property of `report`. calling `setState` in render (during render phase) is an antipattern in React. The main rule - is relay on state, fetch data needed to render your component from state data, use it inside `render`

Answer (score -1):

according to mobx documentation if you want a variable to trigger your render you should use observable, so it looks like you don't need to use state at all in that case, because observable would trigger render and in your render function you should ask if report is not null and if so just open your modal without changing your state.
am i missing something?

Comment: Yes I am aware of those things, but that's not what I am searching for. Want the component controls it modal not the store

Comment: if you have a special cause to do it that way you can check if report is not null on componentDidUpdate, and then trigger setState but be aware of infinite loop